# Gedit doesn't work in Kali 2020

Tags: kali-linux, virtual-machine, vmware, gedit

Kali 2020 doesn't come with gedit pre-installed.

After installing with

```
sudo apt-get install gedit
```

and trying to run, I get an error message:

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[/root]
└─$ gedit test.txt
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:3673): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:16:31.911: cannot open display:
```

How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**

I'm actually running a Kali virtual machine with VMWARE.

Comment: In the context of Kali: Do you log in as root or as an ordinary user? Do you have a GUI? Are you familiar with Linux-based systems?

Comment: Try entering `export DISPLAY=0:0` into your terminal and then try to open gedit (again from the terminal).

Comment: Sorry all, I'm a Linux beginner. I needed to restart the terminal in order to make it work.